# Uploaded image is broken after writing to file

Tags: python, flask

I have an image which I got from a post request. I want to save it in my files directory. I use the following code to write it to a file, but afterwards the file doesn't show the image. How do I correctly save the file?

```
img = form.imagen.data
filename = secure_filename(img)
path=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
with open(path, 'wb+') as f:
    f.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any code that actually does the write

Comment: hummm you think i should do a f.write()? but it requires a parameter, should i use f.write(img)? because i already tried that and it doesnt save the image properly

Comment: yup, that's what you need

Comment: but it doesnt save the image properly and it also says

builtins.TypeError
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: I had a quick look for the docs. It seems you should be able to do `form.imagen.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))`. Assuming imagen is what I think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't open and write the file yourself use the Flask framework to abstract that for you

```
img = request.files['imugen']
filename = secure_filename(img.filename)
img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: it shows 
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

Alright found the problem, it was this line of code

```
filename = secure_filename(img)
```

and thanks to Leon and the others it worked using the read method in the image and just writted it down:

```
img = form.imagen.data
path=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], img.filename)
with open(path, 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(img.read())
```